# how to add swipe and header view to uiTableView controller.?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3, swipe

[image: this the first screenshort]

[image]

I have added one header view and swipe left to table view controller .

As u can see in screenshot when i swipe the row then the header view is also moving please help me.

my code to add header is

```
     func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

            let header = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "HeaderCell") as! CustomHeaderTableViewCell

            header.SortButton?.backgroundColor = UIColor(netHex:0xEEEEEE)
            header.FilterButton?.backgroundColor = UIColor(netHex:0xEEEEEE)

            header.SortButton?.font = UIFont.fontAwesome(ofSize: 18)
            header.SortButton?.text = String.fontAwesomeIcon(name: .sort) + " Sort"

            header.FilterButton?.font = UIFont.fontAwesome(ofSize: 18)
            header.FilterButton?.text = String.fontAwesomeIcon(name: .filter) + " Filter"

            return header

        }



 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {
        let more = UITableViewRowAction(style: .normal, title: "More") { action, index in
            print("more button tapped")
        }
        more.backgroundColor = .lightGray

        let favorite = UITableViewRowAction(style: .normal, title: "Favorite") { action, index in
            print("favorite button tapped")
        }
        favorite.backgroundColor = .orange

        let share = UITableViewRowAction(style: .normal, title: "Share") { action, index in
            print("share button tapped")
        }
        share.backgroundColor = .blue

        return [share, favorite, more]
    }

     func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    func scrollViewWillBeginDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        searchBar.endEditing(true)

        let translation = scrollView.panGestureRecognizer.translation(in: scrollView.superview)

        if(translation.y > 0)
        {
            // react to dragging down
        } else
        {
            // react to dragging up
        }
    }
```

can please help me to solve the problem of swipe .

and one more thing can I hide the header view on scroll .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 possible solutions to your problem:

1. Simply return `cell.contentView` instead of cell within your `viewForHeaderInSection` function and your problem will be resolved.
2. Subclass `UITableViewHeaderFooterView` instead of `UITableViewCell` for your Header view.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `UITableViewCell` subclass as a Header view. Instead use [`UITableViewHeaderFooterView`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableviewheaderfooterview#overview)